# Best practices D8 config:export:content:type VS Features module

Tags: drupal-8

I'm a bit lost with the new config system. In Drupal 7, I put all my content type, blocks, views, etc. in differents Features.

In D8, [drupal config:export:content:type](https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/commands/config-export-content-type.html) seems to do exactly what [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) do.

Except for the UI do I have advantages to still use the Features module or should I create my custom modules and use config:export commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests, I realise that I don't need Features.

My workflow is `drush cex -y` and `drush cim` and it's enought.